# how to reference previous elements in a pandas dataframe column to calculate further elements based on conditions being met

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create a loop which will populate a column based on previous values in the column.

basically i want to look to see if in the previous row the "purchase column" is equal to 1 and if so i want the "hold column to contain 5's until the "sell check column reads a 1 at which time i want the hold column to the display a -1.

i have tried:

```
dt['Hold'] = pd.np.where(dt['Purchase'].shift(1) ==1, pd.np.where(dt['Sell_Check'] != 1,5,-1),pd.np.where(dt['Hold'].shift(1) == 5 , pd.np.where(dt['Sell_Check'] != 1,5,-1),0 ) )
```

this did the first part fine but it did not contiue to add 5's until the sell check =1 .

i ahve also tried:

```
 for i in range (1, len(dt)):
             if dt.loc[i-1, 'Purchase'] == 1 and dt.loc[i, 'Sell_Check'] != 1:
                 dt.loc[i , 'Hold'] = 5
             elif dt.loc[i-1, 'Hold'] == 5 and dt.loc[i, 'Sell_Check'] != 1:
                dt.loc[i, 'Hold'] = 5
             elif dt.loc[i, 'Sell_Check'] == 1:
                dt.loc[i, 'Hold'] = -1
             else:
                 dt.loc[i, 'Hold'] = 0
```

but this returns "keyerror: 15" which doesnt tell me much.

any help would be apreciated and if what i am trying to acheive isnt clear please let me know and i will try to explain more

sample data:
what it currently looks like:

```
         Date  Purchase  Sell_Check  Hold
0    20190107         0           0     0
1    20190108         1           0     0
2    20190109         0           0     5
3    20190110         0           0     0
4    20190111         1           0     0
5    20190114         0           1    -1
6    20190115         0           0     0
```

what i would like it to look like:

```
     Date  Purchase  Sell_Check  Hold
20190107         0           0     0
20190108         1           0     0
20190109         0           0     5
20190110         0           0     5
20190111         0           0     5
20190114         0          -1     5
20190115         0           0    -1
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result (as text, not as a picture).

Comment: added, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following function with "memory feature":

```
def getHold(row):
    rv = getHold.prevVal
    if row.Purchase == 1:
        getHold.prevVal = 5
    if row.Sell_Check == 1:
        getHold.prevVal = -1
    return rv
```

The mentioned "memory feature" is implemented as *prevVal* attribute
of this function.

This attribute will be set to the initial value (*0*) before the first call.

Then, on each application (to consecutive rows of *df*) this function:

- sets the return value (*rv*) from *prevVal*,
- then conditionally changes *prevVal* to either *5* or *-1*,
- but this value will be returned on the **next** time.

To get the result, apply this function, saving the result in *Hold* column
(it may even not exist before):

```
getHold.prevVal = 0   # Set the initial value of "prevVal"
df['Hold'] = df.apply(getHold, axis=1)
```

As far as *Hold* column is concerned, the result is just as you want.

In your expected result I see also some changes in other columns,
but you wrote only about setting of values in *Hold* column.
This is why I assume that changes in other columns are your mistakes.

## Edit

If *-1* should be returned **only once** and then *0* again, change the
function to:

```
def getHold(row):
    rv = getHold.prevVal
    if getHold.prevVal == -1:
        getHold.prevVal = 0
    if row.Purchase == 1:
        getHold.prevVal = 5
    if row.Sell_Check == 1:
        getHold.prevVal = -1
    return rv
```

Then test it on source DataFrame containing another row with consecutive
*Date* and both *Purchase* and *Sell_Check* == 0.
The last returned value will be *0*.

Comment: that works amazingly thank you very much, sorry my examples were a little confusing, i altered the purchase and sell columns to try to provide the specific example of what i wanted in the hold column without thinking that would make things confusing.

one last thing i would like to ask, the code you provided works well but it would make subsequent calcualtions i aim to perform easier if 0's were returned after an intial -1 was returned. basically only the 5's continue to run and not the -1's